# Create spinner adapter in android dialog builder

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-alertdialog

I have a problem with spinner in my alert dialog builder, it does not show any error while compilation time and I also call `alertdialog.show()` method to show my custom dialog but it can't populate my spinner items. Here is my code

```
public Dialog add_pop_up()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UgJadwal.this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = UgJadwal.this.getLayoutInflater();
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.addpopup, null));
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.add);
    builder.setTitle("Add new schedule");

    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.add, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
        {
            day = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.day);
            subject = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.subject);
            time = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.time);
            location = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.location);
            lecture = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lecture);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterDay = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(UgJadwal.this, R.array.day, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapterDay.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            day.setAdapter(adapterDay);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
        {
            //
        }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
```

Logcat:

```
03-17 20:14:59.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9889): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 20:14:59.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9889): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-17 20:14:59.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9889):     at com.rk.ug_simplify.UgJadwal$3.onClick(UgJadwal.java:195)
03-17 20:14:59.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9889):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:158)
03-17 20:14:59.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9889):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-17 20:14:59.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9889):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-17 20:14:59.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9889):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-17 20:14:59.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9889):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-17 20:14:59.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9889):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-17 20:14:59.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9889):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-17 20:14:59.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9889):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-17 20:14:59.030: E/AndroidRuntime(9889):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

UPDATE! above is my logcat, but that error point to the another context of custom dialog.
Does any body know my mistakes? I appreciate for any help, thanks!

UPDATE 2!! Adding views

```
public Dialog add_pop_up()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UgJadwal.this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = UgJadwal.this.getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addpopup, null);
    builder.setView(dialogview);
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.add);
    builder.setTitle("Add new schedule");

    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.add, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
        {
            day = (Spinner)dialogview.findViewById(R.id.day);
            subject = (EditText)dialogview.findViewById(R.id.subject);
            time = (EditText)dialogview.findViewById(R.id.time);
            location = (Spinner)dialogview.findViewById(R.id.location);
            lecture = (EditText)dialogview.findViewById(R.id.lecture);

            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterDay = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(UgJadwal.this, R.array.day, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapterDay.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            day.setAdapter(adapterDay);
            String sub = subject.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(UgJadwal.this, "Success " + sub, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace from logcat?

Answer (score 0):

if Spinner is inside  `Dialog` layout then you will need to use Dialog Layout instance to access it. change your code as :

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UgJadwal.this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = UgJadwal.this.getLayoutInflater();

    // inflate layout to View 
    View dialogview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);

    builder.setView(dialogview);  //<< set view for Dialog

    //....your code here....

    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.add, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
        {
          day = (Spinner)dialogview.findViewById(R.id.day); //<< access Spinner

          // do same for other Views to access it from dialogview
          // your code here...
```

Comment: well I tried your code, but the compiler prompt me to change the modifier of `dialogview` into `final`. I did it but is still doesn't work.

Comment: @RadityaKurnianto : you also need to change for other views which u want to get from  Dialog EditText ,TextView's,...

Comment: @RadityaKurnianto : which error u are getting plz edit your question with latest code and logcat results becuase it's possible u have other issue in current code.

Comment: you mean change it to be like this? `subject = (EditText)dialogview.findViewById(R.id.subject);`

Comment: @RadityaKurnianto : yes i mean if EditText is also inside `dialog_layout` layout then use `subject = (EditText)dialogview.findViewById(R.id.subject);` and do same for other Views

Comment: well. would you like to check my update 2 section, I have added view for the control that I need, but the spinner is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Getradius() {
    // Set up download interaction. Display a dialog
    // when the user clicks download button and require
    // a user-provided region name
    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(class.this);

    final Spinner min_zoom=new Spinner(class.this);
    final Spinner max_zoom=new Spinner(class.this);


    ArrayAdapter min = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_item_register, minzoom_values);
    min.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    min_zoom.setAdapter(min);

    // Build the dialog box
    builder.setTitle("Set Radius")
            .setView(min_zoom)
            .setPositiveButton("GET COURSE LIST", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    // Display the dialog
    builder.show();
}
```